# DI Exception in ASP.NET Core: Could not create an instance of type 'MyProject.Data.ITableRepositories'

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, azure-table-storage, asp.net-core-1.1

I try to follow the article [Access Azure Storage in an ASP.NET Core application using Connected Services](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/visualstudio/1328/visual-studio-connected-services-aspnet-core-azure-storage), under ASP.NET Core 1.1 in order to connect my web application to Azure Tables.

But the problem is that under ASP.NET Core and `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage` nuget I have no acces to the Syncronous methods.

I am a beginner with async programming, so probably the code bellow is a little bit crazy, however this is my version of the "Async Azure Connector":

```
// Model
public class Record : TableEntity {
    public Record() { }
    public Record(string id, string name, string partition = "record") {
        this.RowKey = id;
        this.PartitionKey = partition;
        this.Name = name;
    }
    [...]
}    

// Data Interface
public interface ITableRepositories {
    Task<bool> CreateRecordAsync(Record record);
    Task<List<Record>> GetRecordsAsync();
    Task<Record> GetRecordAsync(string key, string partitionKey = "record");
}

// Data Class
public class TableClientOperationsService : ITableRepositories {
    private string connectionString;
    private CloudTable recordTable;

    public TableClientOperationsService() { }
    public TableClientOperationsService(IOptions<AppSecrets> optionsAccessor) {
        connectionString = optionsAccessor.Value.MyProjectTablesConnectionString;
    }

    public CloudTable RecordTable {
        get {
            if (recordTable == null) {
                recordTable = GetTable("Record");
            }
            return recordTable;
        }
    }

    private CloudTable GetTable(string tableName) {
        [.connectionString.]
        table.CreateIfNotExistsAsync().Wait();
        return table;
    }

    public async Task<T> Get<T>(string partitionKey, string rowKey, string tableName) where T : ITableEntity, new()
    {            [...]        }

    public async Task<bool> CreateRecordAsync(Record record) {
        TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(record);
        await this.RecordTable.ExecuteAsync(insertOperation);
        return true;
    }

    public async Task<Record> GetRecordAsync(string key, string partitionKey = "record") {
        const string TableName = "Record";
        Record myRecord = await Get<Record>(partitionKey, key, TableName);
        return myRecord;
    }

    public async Task<List<Record>> GetRecordsAsync() {
        TableQuery<Record> recordsQuery = new TableQuery<Record>().Where(
            TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "record"));
        EntityResolver<Record> recordResolver = null;
        List<Record> myList = new List<Record>();
        TableQuerySegment<Record> currentSegment = null;
        while (currentSegment == null || currentSegment.ContinuationToken != null) {
            currentSegment = await recordTable.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(
                recordsQuery,
                recordResolver,
                currentSegment != null ? currentSegment.ContinuationToken : null);

            myList.AddRange(currentSegment.Results);
        }
        return myList;
    }
}

// Setup.cs configuration
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddOptions();
    services.Configure<AppSecrets>(Configuration);

    // association of ITableRepositories with TableClientOperationsService
    services.AddSingleton(typeof(ITableRepositories), typeof(TableClientOperationsService));

    services.AddMvc();        
}


// Usage in the Controller
public class HelloWorldController : Controller {
    public async Task<string> ReadTables1(ITableRepositories repository) {
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        response.AppendLine("Here is your Record Table:");
        var items = await repository.GetRecordsAsync();
        foreach (Record item in items) {
            response.AppendLine($"RowKey: {item.RowKey}; Name: {item.Name}");
        }
        return response.ToString();
    }
```

However, when I try to acces the controller action via `/HelloWorld/ReadTables1` 
it trows me the following:

> InvalidOperationException: Could not create an instance of type 'MyProject.Data.ITableRepositories'. Model bound complex types must not be abstract or value types and must have a parameterless constructor.

Probably I registered it incorrectly in the services, because my TableClientOperationsService class is not abstract and has a parameter less constructor? How to fix it?

Comment: My bad mis-read

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should get the ITableRepositories parameter in constructor of controller, not in method to get it from DI.

```
public class HelloWorldController : Controller
{
    private readonly ITableRepositories _tableRepository;
    public HelloWorldController(ITableRepositories tableRepository)
    {
         _tableRepository = tableRepository;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are my hero ! :) I caught the following error in `GetRecordsAsync` method, because EntityResolver is null, I have no idea what to put there !